# Grails Tomcat OutofMemory error

Tags: tomcat, grails

I have a Grails app that I have packed with the war command: `grails war`. I need to deploy it to a remote machine running Tomcat.

When I do the drop deploy (copying the WAR file into `C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\webapps`) and run `C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\bin\startup.bat` I am getting several `OutofMemory` errors with PermGem and Heap space.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I usually do when starting tomcat :

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"; export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"; /etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart; tail -f /var/lib/tomcat6/logs/catalina.out
```

That fixes all memory problems. I have 6 Grails applications running with that configuration.

Comment: You don't need to set CATALINA_OPTS, if JAVA_OPTS are specified exactly the same way (CATALINA_OPTS are JAVA_OPTS for the "start" command only).

Comment: yes from the command line. the path /etc/init.d/tomcat6 may differ if you don't use ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

On the Tomcat server, add a system environment variable:  JAVA_OPTS -Xmx512m

Also, in your Grails app in the conf/BuildConfig.groovy add the line at the following line at the top:
grails.tomcat.jvmArgs= ["-Xms256m",  "-Xmx1024m", "-XX:PermSize=512m", "-XX:MaxPermSize=512m"]

This seems to have solved many of the issues I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, I'd recommend editing /etc/default/tomcat6 (or tomcat7 depending on what you're running).

Around line 20 is a sample JAVA_OPTS line; uncomment it, and edit it to suit your hardware.

I've got mine running as:

```
 JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

Which caps the RAM in use at a gig, and sets permsize to 512m.

Answer (score 0):

Use the default values on Grails Build.config 
Change on this point:

```
grails.project.fork = [
// configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
//  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

// configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: true, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
// configure settings for the run-app JVM
run: [maxMemory: 500, minMemory: 64, debug: true, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
// configure settings for the run-war JVM
war: [maxMemory: 500, minMemory: 64, debug: true, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
// configure settings for the Console UI JVM
console: [maxMemory: 500, minMemory: 64, debug: true, maxPerm: 256]
```

]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using service based tomcat then you may not have catalina.bat file in bin folder.
Then try to add these java options.
[image]