# How to set the MaxPermSize in Grails 2.2 running on Tomcat 7 0 39?

Tags: tomcat, grails, tomcat7, grails-2.0

When running my Grails application on Tomcat I want to increase the **MaxPermSize**. Is there some flag I can set in the config.groovy or do I have to modify the Tomcat configuration?

How do I config the MaxPermSize for a grails app when running in development on STS or Eclipse and in production on a Tomcat Server?

Comment: Possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573803/grails-tomcat-outofmemory-error

Comment: have you seen this question, did it not work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260645/increase-xmx-and-xms-for-grails-run-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MaxPermSize` is a JVM option. It has to be set as `JAVA_OPTS` for whichever version of JVM you use. For Example:

`JAVA_OPTS =-server -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Comment: I use GGTS with build in Tomcat. Where do I have to set JAVA_OPTS?

Comment: If you want to make GGTS work better for your workspace then you have to look at `GGTS.ini` file inside the GGTS installation directory. In case you want to increase the grails app performance while run-app/debug, you can add VM arguments in `Run Configuration -> Grails -> Your Project` in GGTS.